# Some of your locations overlap. Try removing a location. (Facebook marketing API)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ads, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

In Facebook Marketing API, trying to get estimated audience size on the basis of country, state and city.
For example I want to know how big the audience size of people who lives in India ("country_code": "IN"), Maharashtra("region_id":"1735"), Navi Mumbai("key":"2677331").
the http request which I am trying is

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/ad_acc_d/reachestimate?fields=users,estimate_ready&targeting_spec={"geo_locations": { "countries": [ "IN" ], "regions": [ { "key" : "1735" } ], "cities": [ { "key": "2677331"} ]      } }
```

When I hit the request using graph api explorer it says

```
"error_user_title": "Locations can't be used",
"error_user_msg": "Some of your locations overlap. Try removing a location."
```

I want to get the audience size on the basis of country, state and city. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You should only provide the most specific location you wish to target, in this case, the city of Navi Mumbai (`"key": "2677331"`). Conversely, if you wish to target the entire Maharashtra region, provide that, and that only. The same goes for India.

Therefore, in case you're only targeting the city, your request should look like this:

```
act_{account_id}/reachestimate?fields=users,estimate_ready&targeting_spec={"geo_locations": { "cities": [ { "key" : "2677331" } ] } }
```